# Counting array accesses

Tags: java, arrays, complexity-theory

I am trying to figure out how to determine the complexity(array accesses) of certain simple methods.

I'd like some confirmation if I'm doing this right.
For example this method.

```
    int i = 0;  
    while(i < N){
        clone[i][j] = clone[++i][j];
        clone[i][j] = 0;
    }
```

Do the array accesses sum up to three here? One for`clone[i][j]` another for `clone[++i][j]` and lastly another one for `clone[i][j]`. Meaning this has ± `3N` array accesses?

How about something like this:

`if(clone[i][j] == value1 || clone[i][j] == value2)`

Can I consider this to be one array access, or two?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes.  Your logic seems solid.

Comment: @JustinKSU Thanks for your input, I've added another case of which I am unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd count these as **six** array accesses.

You are accessing 2D arrays, and a statement like

```
clone[i][j] = 0;
```

could be written analogously as

```
int temp[] = clone[i];
temp[j] = 0;
```

You can also have a look at the bytecode: A a class like

```
class ArrayAcc
{
    static void foo()
    {
        int array[][] = new int[2][2];
        array[1][1] = 123;
    }

}
```

compiled and disassembled with

> javap -c ArrayAcc.class

gives the following output:

```
....
static void foo();
Code:
   0: iconst_2
   1: iconst_2
   2: multianewarray #2,  2             // class "[[I"
   6: astore_0
   7: aload_0
   8: iconst_1
   9: aaload
  10: iconst_1
  11: bipush        123
  13: iastore
  14: return
```

The `aaload` instruction loads the reference to the "inner" array on the stack. The `iastore` instruction puts the value `123` into this "inner" array.

---

For the other part of the question,

```
if(clone[i][j] == value1 || clone[i][j] == value2)
```

Here it depends on whether the first condition is `true` or not. If the first condition is `true`, then the second one will **not** be evaluated. If you wrote

```
if(clone[i][j] == value1 | clone[i][j] == value2)
```

(with a single `|`) then you'd always check *both* conditions.

Comment: for the second case, if you were looking to minimize array accesses wouldn't it make more sense to store the value in a local variable?

Comment: @user2573153 The question was not about *minimizing* the number of array accesses, but about *counting* them. This is difficult in any case. But I wanted to point out that `a[i][j]=x;` should probably not be considered as a single array access. (In order to minimize the number of array accesses, there would be different options, but whether these would bring *any* advantage in practice is yet another question...)